# Vue event listener with internal and external parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I add an internal and external parameter to an event listener at the same time?

```html
<myComp @do="wrapDo($event, 5)"></myComp>
```

```js
function wrapDo(objectFromComp, myIntegerParameter){
    // objectFromComp is okey :)
    // myIntegerParameter is undefined :(
}
```

In `myComp.vue`:

```
this.$emit('do', { text: "return object from component"} );
```

I tried this but get `undefined`:

```js
@do="x => wrapDo(x, 5)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine, just make sure you have that function in `methods`:

```js
Vue.component('mycomp', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <button @click="$emit('do', { text: 'return object from component'})">Emit</button>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    wrapDo(objectFromComp, myIntegerParameter) {
      console.log(objectFromComp, myIntegerParameter);
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <mycomp @do="wrapDo($event, 5)"></mycomp>
</div>
```

Comment: thx @dan dont know that happing but all work after restart VSCode